# SSRS 2008 Export to Microsoft Word does not include headers and footers

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reporting, export-to-word

I have a report, which was recently converted from SSRS2005 to SSRS2208.

The report header has a background, which is calculated depending on the page number. In the report footer there is an image and two text boxes, also calculated depending on page number.

The report preview in the Business Intelligence Development Studio displays correctly, exporting to PDF also works correctly. However, when exporting to Microsoft Word the header and footers disappear and page margins increase by about 1.5cm.

---

The margins part of this issue has been reported in Microsoft Connect and resolved. The fix should be "in SqlServer2008R2 CTP3 and beyond".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From some experimenting, it seems that the export to Word Document feature doesn't work if

- header or footer items have properties that are calculated depending on the page number
- headers and footers have background images

**Simplifying the header and footer contents should make them to appear.**

There are probably more situations where the headers and footers don't export to Microsoft Word, than the two I've listed. As far as I'm aware there isn't a way to get more complex headers and footers to work with the export to Word Document feature.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how to do it, but I might have an idea. In SSRS 2005, with export to Excel you had to change the Excel Device Information Settings in the config file of SSRS to use SimplePageHeaders: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155069(SQL.90).aspx (How to: http://mysqlserverblog.com/2008/01/03/changing-export-options-for-reporting-services.aspx)

I looked up the Word Device Information Settings, but as far as I can tell, there no such setting: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281123.aspx

But good luck!

Comment: Thank you :) That list of settings for Word doesn't look very promising (or extensive) unfortunately, but its handy to know its there. I might be able to fix the margins problem with those options at least, I'll give it a shot on Monday

Answer (score 0):

I have a report where the header and footer is exported correctly however on the first page Word interprets the footer to be different and for some reason hides it. There appears to be a little height difference between the first and the rest of the pages.

If you edit the footer ther is a checkbox in Word 2007 and 2010 that allows you to show it anyway. Don't know why SSRS exports it differently between the first and other pages.