# Create Report Header as Part of Large Rectangle in Body

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I want to set up a report with an image in the header on every page but that it has to be part of the large rectangle that covers the body.  All other contents will be in that rectangle.

How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the logo `image` in the `header` section as you want. And then set the report `BorderStyle` and `BorderWidth` properties as per your requirements.

For example, for the following image in the header,

[image]

with following settings:

[image].

will result as something like following:

[image]

Hope this help?

Comment: That worked when I exported the report to PDF!  However, the border did not show up in Word.  Any ideas?

Comment: Yes. SSRS has the problem with exporting the `MS Word`. For reference, check the answer in this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519419/ssrs-2008-export-to-microsoft-word-does-not-include-headers-and-footers)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! You would think that Microsoft would have resolved this by Sql Server 2012!

Comment: Can't comment at the moment as busy in a deadline but will check in a couple of days. Hopefully, someone else will jump in with a solution by that time. Fingers crossed :)